# git installation needed on remote server which is access via ssh only

Tags: git

I'm trying to do an access from a remote machine to a server machine which currently does not contain any git installation. The question is: Does the server machine need a git installation in any kind (i assume it needs) to work from the client only via ssh with git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes you need git on the server

Without git on the server, you can't push/pull to the remote. The protocol you use to act remotely on your git repo, doesn't change this.

### Poor mans git

You can if you really need/want to just rsync your .git directory to a remote server. Because all files in the .git/objects directory are based on a hash, you won't get any collisions.

That would mean in principle:

```
# git push
rsync -rv .git server:repo.git

# git pull
rsync -rv server:repo.git .git
git reset HEAD --hard # Here lies the problem with this technique.
```

Comment: That's what I expected. Thanks.

Comment: The problem I had was an old server without Git installation and no available package so I thought it could be made without updating the server but I expected that it was not possible. The rsync part is known to me. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried what has been suggested here in the past and only ever get 'git-upload-pack: command not found' since the upload and pack service isn't available to the remote server.  Maybe I am missing something but it really does look like you need git installed on each machine that wants to play a part in it.

Comment: Answer reverted to original version (which is the one that was accepted) as it's evident that when testing on a server without git, I infact tested on a server which did have git installed.

Answer (score 1):

You need a Git installation on the server, to setup a real remote repository on the server i can suggest you [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) that works fine ...

Comment: unless you need fine-grained permissions, gitolite is completely unnecessary. The only requirement to use git, is to intsall git.

Comment: Yes, i know but Gitolite is powerful and could result very useful for future management requests ...